How to sync Safari, Chrome, Firefox bfcache behaviour?
I'm frustrated because Chrome, Firefox has different behaviours with bfcache in my React web app. When users use the back and forward buttons in Safari, they can return using back/forward and my web page isn't refreshed. Chrome and Firefox refresh the page on return.
What can I do to make the behaviors the same? It almost doesn't matter which behavior they do, as long as they all do it.
Is the only solution to single out Safari in the onbeforeunload or pageshow window event listeners and do something different?
